# How to construct json text using string?

Tags: json, perl

I'm trying to construct json text as show below. But the variables such as $token, $state, $failedServers are not been replaced with its value. Note- I don't want to use any module specifically for this to work, I just want some plain string to work. Can anyone help me ?

```
my $json = '{"serverToken":"$token", "state":"$state","parameters" :"$failedServers"}';
```

current output was:

```
{"serverToken":"$token", "state":"$state","parameters" :"$failedServers"}
```

needed output format:

```
{"serverToken":"1213", "state":"failed","parameters" :"oracleapps.veeralab.com,suntrust.com"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variables are not being replaced, because they are inside of a single-quoted string--that is, they are inside a string quoted by `'` characters.  This prevents variable substitution.

You will also be much better off creating JSON using a JSON library, such as [this one](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm). Simply using a quoted string is very dangerous.  Suppose your one of your variables ends up containing a special character; you will end up with invalid JSON.

```
{"serverToken":"123"ABC", "state":"offline", "paramameters":"bugs"}
```

If your variables come from user input, really bad things could happen.  Imagine that $token is set to equal `foo", "state":"online", "foo":"bar`.  Your resulting JSON structure would be:

```
{"serverToken":"foo", "state":"online", "foo":"bar", "state":"offline" ...
```

Certainly not what you want.

---

Possible solutions:

The most blatantly obvious solution is simply not to the `'` quote character. This has the drawback of requiring you to escape your double quote (`"`) characters, though, but it's easy:

```
my $json = "{\"serverToken\":\"$token\", \"state\":\"$state\",\"parameters\" :\"$failedServers\"}";
```

Another option is to use sprintf:

```
my $json = sprintf('{"serverToken":"%s", "state":"%s", "parameters":"%s"}', $token, $state, $failedServers);
```

But by far, the best solution, because it won't break with wonky input, is to use a library:

```
use JSON;
my $json = encode_json( {
    serverToken => $token,
    state => $state,
    paramaters => $failedServers
} );
```

Comment: I don't want to use any library. Can you suggest what I need to correct for it to work?

Comment: @user1595858: Yes, don't quote your string using the `'` character, as I said in my answer.

Comment: @user1595858: Also, why don't you want to use a library? It's the most secure way to do what you need.

Comment: I don't want to install any new library as I don't have privilege as root.

Comment: @user1595858: You don't need to be root to install Perl libraries. If you have access to run a perl script you write, you have access to install the perl libraries you need.

Comment: @user1595858: You can ask a separate question about that; but I'm sure it's been answered a million times. Try google first.

Comment: I used to use cpan to install libraries but that needs root because I tried it before. Is there someother way that doesn't need root?

Comment: @user1595858: As I said, you can ask a separate question about that, but I'm sure it's been answered a million times. Try google first.

Comment: The backslashes are not the only way out - `my $json = qq({"serverToken":"123"ABC",...);` works just as well. See [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) for more.

Comment: @Zaid: Indeed, there are other ways, too... they all suck compared to using a proper library :)